# Is there a way to display a div with width in % and no content?

Tags: html, css, shapes

For example this div is displayed:

```
<div class="circle"></div

.circle { 
   width: 300px;
   height: 300px;
   background: red; 
   border-radius: 50%;
}
```

but when width and height are in % it collapses:

```
.circle { 
       width: 30%;
       height: 30%;
       background: red; 
       border-radius: 50%;
    }
```

Is there a way to get it displayed?

Comment: A little more code would be helpful.  What element is this `div` inside?

Comment: What are the dimensions of the parent container?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because the div has no height. `width: 30%;` will always make the div 30% width of the parent (`<body>`, in this case), which is what you want. However, height behaves a little differently.

You need to specify a 100% height for body and html like so:

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w5LSK/)

You can read why `height: 100%;` behaves like that [here](http://webdesign.about.com/od/csstutorials/f/set-css-height-100-percent.htm)

Comment: False information - width 30% makes the div 30% of the width of the *parent element* - *not* the browser.

Comment: @Adrian In OP's example, the parent was body, so essentially the same thing. Edited though.

Comment: @marcelo2605 That's because the `<body/>` height is not square. Better solution would be to put the circle div in a container that can be independently resized of the body.

Answer (score 3):

You need to declare a hard width/height somewhere, in this example I put a hard width/height on a container div:

http://jsfiddle.net/exrNm/1/

```
<div class="con">
    <div class="circle"></div
</div>

.con{
    width:300px;
    height:300px
}

.circle { 
   width: 30%;
   height: 30%;
   background: red; 
   border-radius: 50%;
}
```

You could easily set a hard width somewhere up the parent chain.  The % needs a hard value to calculate against.